# Check for overflow condition in an arithmetic operation

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

how do we check if any arithmetic operation like addition, multiplication or subtraction could result in an overflow?

Comment: my question is specially towards unsigned integers

Comment: Strictly speaking, unsigned arithmetic does not overflow; it wraps around in a well defined manner.  But that's just a quibble about the meaning of the word "overflow", and it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the size of the operands first, and use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/). For example, for addition:

```
#include <limits>

unsigned int a, b;  // from somewhere

unsigned int diff = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() - a;

if (diff < b) { /* error, cannot add a + b */ }
```

You cannot generally and reliably detect arithmetic errors *after* the fact, so you have to do all the checking before.

You can easily template this approach to make it work with any numeric type.

Comment: Hi,is there any method using some logic and without using any template to solve this problem?

Comment: I thought you could detect after: `a += b;  if (a<b) {//overflow}`, or is this not reliable?

Comment: @pravs: replace `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` with `UINT_MAX`

Comment: @pravs: I mean, you get the general idea, but using `numeric_limts` is by far the most uniform, readable, self-explanatory and portable way. Is there any reason *not* to use it? You could also say "is there a way to write C++ without classes or `for` loops"... but why?

Comment: i am unaware about "numeric_limits".could you suggest me some source from where i could get the idea?

Comment: @pravs: I did add a link, just click on it. Otherwise, read any decent C++ book to learn more about the language -- the FAQ has a good list, I believe. If all else fails, Stroustrup's book is always a good idea. I'd also suggest that you don't design your life around the "avoid anything I don't know yet" idea, but rather go for "how do I learn how to do things better?". :-)