# How do i handle arithmetic overflows ?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, arithmetic-expressions

i am trying to figure out how to handle overflow for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, for two very large integer numbers. Any feedback/input would be appreciated. Does anyone know any algorithms for this and/or sources I could consult?

(I have done research before posting and am just not sure how to tackle this and)

EDIT: for two very large integer numbers

Comment: What do you mean by handle? Throw an error, return a certain number (e.g. 0), or use bigger numbers so there is no overflow?

Comment: which big number library are you using? check **the documentation**

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking "How can I know when a (floating-point) addition/subtraction/multiplication/division operation will overflow, and what are the usual methods for dealing with such cases?"

Comment: k well when you add two very large numbers there is overflow, so I am asking how you would handle this. Is that a cleareR?

Comment: @Serdalis by overflow i mean to handle it so it does not go pass the bounds. Okay suppose I would have fractions. 2/3 + 1/2 is a case now imagine the numerators have very large numbers and you are adding them how would you handle this to prevent overflow?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to the questions
[Check for overflow condition in an arithmetic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932340/check-for-overflow-condition-in-an-arithmetic-operation)
and
[How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the condition of overflow occurring, one way would be to use a linked list to store parts of a number and then perform calculations on the parts individually, and  add more nodes to the list to handle the excess digits when needed.

Example

1234567890 can be stored as -> 12,34,56,78,90
To multiply, each unit will be multiplied and carry taken over to next unit -> 1,23,45,67,89,0

Keep in mind though, that it is easier to divide it into single digit units, like 1,2,3,4,5 rather than 1,23,45 as this makes the operations simpler.

EDIT :: The word "handle" is not the word you should be using

Answer (score 0):

Because an integer divided by an integer is rarely an integer, this is impossible in general.

That said, this is what I think you want:
http://gmplib.org/

It handles integers and rationals of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder how you can check overflows, I would recommend this:

```
log(a) + log(b) = log(a*b)
```

- Correct => no overflow
- Not correct => overflow

(... and now fingers crossed that nobody finds a contra-example and please, don't start about negative numbers, this is a `uint` approach).